# Avoid Creating Closure in Kendo Dialog Action

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a Kendo dialog which is supposed to respond to user action; user clicks on things 1-3, a dialog appears saying "Hello! Would you like to mess with things 1-3?", and when the user clicks "OK" we fire off an async action telling the server to mess with those things.

Easy enough to do, in theory. The problem is that the `actions.action` function there creates a closure, so if I pop open the dialog for items `[1, 2, 3]` the first time, it will only ever fire that action with `[1, 2, 3]`, as the demo below hopefully demonstrates. How can I fix this so the actions function renews itself each time the dialog opens? My current best solution is to mess with the HTML of the dialog content, so I can scrape it from within the action, but I would prefer a cleaner solution.

```js
function popDialog() {
  // Normally I'd extract this from the HTML, but this will work for a demo.
  const chosenItems = [];
  for (let ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++) {
    const nextNum = Math.floor(10 * Math.random());
    chosenItems.push(nextNum);
  }

  $("#kendoDialog").kendoDialog({
    title: "Kendo Dialog Component",
    content: `<em>I see you're messing with ${chosenItems}</em>`,
    actions: [{
      text: "OK",
      action: function(e) {
        alert(`Now messing with ${chosenItems}`);
      },
      primary: true
    }]
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.224/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.224/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css" />
<div id="kendoDialog" />
<button onClick="popDialog()">Open Dialog</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest solution would be to create and destroy the Dialog widget each time, from a `div` created and appended to the DOM just for this purpose. I've modified your `popDialog` function to demonstrate this.

Please note I've also added a `close` event handler, which destroys the widget instance when the Dialog closes; this in turn cleans up all the markup generated by kendo and frees any event handlers etc.

```js
function popDialog() {
      // Normally I'd extract this from the HTML, but this will work for a demo.
      const chosenItems = [];
      for (let ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++) {
        const nextNum = Math.floor(10 * Math.random());
        chosenItems.push(nextNum);
      }
  
      var dlg = $.parseHTML("<div></div>");
      $("body").append(dlg);
  
      $(dlg).kendoDialog({
        title: "Kendo Dialog Component",
        content: `<em>I see you're messing with ${chosenItems}</em>`,
        actions: [{
          text: "OK",
          action: function(e) {
            alert(`Now messing with ${chosenItems}`);
          },
          primary: true
        }],
        close: function(e) {
          this.destroy();
        }
      });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.224/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.224/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css" />

<button onClick="popDialog()">Open Dialog</button>
```